# Using SSH to grep keywords from multiple servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I am completely new to scripting and am having some trouble piecing this together from some other online resources.

What I want to do is run a bash script that will grep for a keyword domain in the /etc/hosts file on multiple servers.  In the output file, I am looking for a list of the servers that contain this keyword but am not looking to make any changes.  Simply looking for which machines have this value.  Since there are a bunch of machines in question, listing the servers I am looking to search for won't work, but the machine I am doing this from does have SSH keys for all of the ones in question.

I have a listing of the servers I want to query in three files on the machine (one for each environment) I am going to run this script from.

```
Linux.prod.dat
Linux.qa.dat
Linux.dev.dat
```

Each file is simply a list of server names in the environment.  For example..

```
server1
server2
server3 
etc...
```

I am totally lost here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: givepatajob, what's in servername.dat? list of servers?

Comment: Actually, I think I am wrong in referencing that.  It was something I found on a different site, but I can't seem to find anything similar on my main machine.  I removed that from the question.  Apologies.  Perhaps a way to use the known_hosts for root?

Comment: And I was wrong again.  I do have a .dat of available servers it just used a different naming convention.  In this case, it's separated by environment so I have three...
linux.dev.dat
linux.prod.dat
linux.qa.dat

Sorry about that.

Comment: Please add this data to the question and if possible, give an example of what's in these files.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I edited above.  Each .dat is simply a list of all the servernames in each environment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
KEYWORD=foo
SERVERLIST=Linux.prod.dat
OUTPUTLIST=output.dat

for host in $(cat ${SERVERLIST}); do
    if [[ -n "$(ssh ${host} grep '${KEYWORD}' /etc/hosts && echo Y)" ]]; then
        echo ${host} >> ${OUTPUTLIST}
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at this.  I will give that a try and let you know the results, but I think that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: That did get me what I needed.  Thanks a ton for the help on this.

Comment: @givepatajob, well... if it had helped you, perhaps, you could accept the answer?...

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing parens

Answer (score 1):

Try GNU parallel

```
parallel --tag ssh {} grep -l "KEYWORD" /etc/hosts :::: Linux.prod.dat
```

`parallel` run command multiple times substituting`{}`with lines from `Linux.prod.dat` file.
`--tag` switch adds value from the Linux.prod.dat on the beginning of the file. So, the output of the command will look like:

```
server1 /etc/hosts
server5 /etc/hosts
server7 /etc/hosts
```

Where server1, server5, etc. will be names of the servers where `/etc/hosts` contains `KEYWORD`